# Is it possible to read Firebase data without attaching any listeners?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm working on a Firebase Android app and need a way to read data from Firebase without actually attaching any listeners. I don't care in this particular instance if the data changes after the initial read. Is there a way I can directly access a `DataSnapshot` without attaching an EventListener to a Firebase reference? Or is there some other way I can directly read from a Firebase reference with some sort of `ref.getValue()` equivalent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Firebase's REST API to get access to the "raw" data.

From: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html

> You can use any Firebase URL as a REST endpoint. All you need to do is append ".json" to the end of the URL and send a request from your favorite HTTPS client. Note that HTTPS is required. Firebase only responds to encrypted traffic so that your data remains safe.

```
curl https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users/jack/name.json
```

> A successful request will be indicated by a 200 OK HTTP status code. The response will contain the data being retreived:

```
{"first":"Jack", "last": "Sparrow"}
```

That same page also mentions a Java wrapper project: https://github.com/bane73/firebase4j

Comment: Yeah, I know about this. I was just hoping I could avoid messing around with AsyncTasks and parsing JSON and just access the data purely through the Firebase java client.

Answer (score 5):

The [the Java SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/index.html) provides a `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` method, which is equivalent to your ref.getValue(). It is utilized just like `addValueEventListener`, but only retrieves a single value.

```
fb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap) {
        System.out.println(snap.getName() + " -> " + snap.getValue());
    }

    @Override public void onCancelled() { }
});
```

The REST API, as Frank mentioned, is also a great choice.

Comment: How can I store the returned `getValue` gotten from the `onDataChange` method to be used somewhere else.?

Comment: You don't "store" the value to be used somewhere else, since this is an asynchronous event. You "react" to the events. Create an Observable and trigger an event to listeners; pass in a callback to the code invoking this code and trigger that callback when completed; or, explore promises.

Comment: @Johny19 No, it shouldn't. The answer to the OP question is `No` __as Kato explicitly specified__. Kato provided a solution for getting the data __from an event__, which the OP explicitly didn't want.

Comment: @Kato , he don't want to attach listeners !