# Receiving Json from Firebase using Play Java

Tags: java, json, playframework

I'm trying to receive data from Firebase using Java/Play framework. 
According to the Firebase doc(https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html), I can do:

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the example only print the data, but I wish use it outside the listener block

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22324282/4408794 show a simpler alternative, which fit my needs. So, I searched all day and discored the `ws` library. Now I'm trying something like:

```
  JsonNode responseAsJsonNode = WS.url(jsonUrl).get()...;
```

But I don't know how to convert it to a JsonNode

So, I'm trying get the response from jsonUrl and assign it to a JsonNode, then I can process the data, but I can't find a way how to do that.

Basically what I'm trying is curl the json data from Firebase API.

Can someone point me how to achieve it using Play/Java ?

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly got something, I'm using https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request for http request, like:

```
String response = Http.get(url).accept("application/json").body();
```

be sure to import `com.github.kevinsawicki.http.*`