# android firebase - retrieving a field of data without using a listener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get a String from the database based on its key. Here is an example of what I have tried but does not work

```
String jobAddress =  ref.child("Driver").child(username).child("job").getKey();
```

This just returns the key i want the value associated with that key but I can not see a method in the docs that doesnt use a listener.

Here is the JSON from the database I want to return "57 Fake Street Drive,Dublin 15"

```
{
  "Mick" : {
    "job" : "57 Fake Street Drive,Dublin 15",
    "jobFinished" : "1492005731",
    "jobStarted" : "1492005723",
    "jobStatus" : "Completing transaction",
    "lat" : 53.4012796,
    "lon" : -6.4091274,
    "name" : "Mick"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to retrieve data without a listener. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323242/is-it-possible-to-read-firebase-data-without-attaching-any-listeners

Comment: Cheers I dont know how I missed that question. But the single value event listener seems to retrieve the data even if it hasn't changed?

Comment: That is correct. If you're connected to Firebase, a value listener immediate fires with the current value.

Comment: Thats great, the reason I didn't want a listener is because I thought the value would need to change. much appreciated